# Error installing old version of scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm in Jupyter notebooks trying to install an older version of `scikit-learn` because a model that I built was trained using `scikit-learn` version `1.0.2`. I have Python version `3.11.3` installed, and when I run the following code to install the new scikit-learn version, I get an extremely long error message:

`!pip install -U scikit-learn==1.0.2`

Here are some snippets of what the error message says - I have no idea what is going on or how to resolve so any help is appreciated:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: which setuptool and numpy version do you use?